# Setting multpile integers with multiple inputs in Java?

Tags: java, keyboard, integer

First time posting and just a novice at programming so this may come off as a stupid question, but is it possible to set multiple integers with multiple keyboard inputs via Kb.nextInt();

It currently looks like this:

```
Scanner Kb = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter two numbers:");
int num0 = Kb.nextInt(),
    num1 = Kb.nextInt();
```

If anyone has any ideas or if it's not possible please drop a reply.
Many thanks.

edit:
So it appears it was still asking for inputs when run on a different computer than the one compiled on. Unknown reason. Thank you for help.

Comment: Why don't you run the code you have so far. I think that you are really close to what you are looking for!

Comment: your code is work fine what is the problem?

Comment: Thank you for that. Have fixed up original post with reasoning as to why it wasn't working. Had just assumed with my novice experience that it was a problem with my coding.